Javacard multiply shorts
I am trying to convert some Java code to Javacard code, where I cannot use type int or long, but I am running into an issue.
The code I have that I want to convert:
void someFunction(short a, short b)
{
    int x = (int)((int)a * (int)b);
}

Since Javacard cannot use integer types at all, I tried to convert this using a 'multiplyShorts' function, which looks as following:
public static short[] multiplyShorts(short a, short b)
{
    short aHigh = (short)((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
    short aLow  = (short)(a & 0xFF);
    short bHigh = (short)((b >> 8) & 0xFF);
    short bLow  = (short)(b & 0xFF);
    short lowLow = (short)(aLow * bLow);
    short highLow = (short)(aHigh * bLow);
    short lowHigh = (short)(aLow * bHigh);
    short highHigh = (short)(aHigh * bHigh);
    short[] result = new short[2];
    result[1] = (short)(lowLow & 0xFF);
    short carry = (short)((lowLow >> 8) & 0xFF);
    short middle = (short)(highLow + lowHigh + carry);
    result[1] |= (short)((middle & 0xFF) << 8);
    result[0] = (short)((middle >> 8) & 0xFF);
    result[0] = (short)(result[0] + highHigh);
    return result;
}

This code is working in most cases, but not for all {a,b} ∈ {0...65535}, as example the case of a=0xFFFF and b=0xFFFF I would expect:
result[0] = 0xFFFE = 0b11111111_11111110
result[1] = 0x0001 = 0b00000000_00000001

However, the result I get is:
result[0] = 0xFEFE = 0b11111110_11111110 //Spot the difference on this line
result[1] = 0x0001 = 0b00000000_00000001

Can someone explain me what I am missing here, or provide me any help converting my code?

But someFunction is not real, is it?

What do you mean with "real"?

Not real code. It doesn't return a value and does nothing with the value it calculates

This is just to show the problem, the rest of the code is not relevant to understand the problem

Maybe you could use javacardx.framework.math.BigNumber instead of "inventing the wheel" again?

You can just create the two values using assignSigned and then call multiply given my XMas special answer that implements JCInteger. You probably want to use JCSystem.makeTransientByteArray(CLEAR_ON_RESET) if you want to use RAM.
There might be a shortcut as the 16 high bits of the integer that is created are always either 0x0000 or 0xFFFF in your particular situation, but I cannot think of one out of my head, mainly because most of the outcome will rely on the lower bits rather than the higher bits in most situations.
Note that short[] result = new short[2]; creates an array in persistent memory for Java Card classic, something you very likely don't want within a multiply method. It's not just that it puts the result in EEPROM or flash, but also that it will require a call to the garbage manager to clean up.

PS please do test the code, it was written some time ago, and I don't have the unit tests anymore, I'm afraid.

I tried to make a shorter version just for this question by inlining several method and then optimizing it, but it seems to give the wrong answer in that case so I definitely need to debug. Hope I can find my Unit tests again.

Yeah I am aware of the transient byte array. Using byte[] makes it easier to test such things on my host. Your code seem to work as expected, difficult topic to understand since java does not really have unsigned values. Thanks for the answer.

That's why that was an X-mas special answer, as I had to look up the multiplication strategies which were mostly for C and then convert it for Java with signed bytes and shorts. Very likely at least in the top 100 most complex answers ever written for SO. It basically replaced the X-mas puzzle :P

Found this a bit fun so figured I'd throw it in here. But if one needs better Integer support the XMAS special from Maarten Bodewes is probably something you go for anyway.
That said, the issue in the code comes from missing out on the carry that can happen in the variable you have called middle. Finding the carry is a bit more complex than the carry on the lowLow as it can overflow the short value. You both need to check if there is a overflow for the sum of highLow and lowHigh, and also a bit of a corner case where adding the carry from lowLow overflows the sum from highLow and lowHigh.
So code would become:
public static short[] multiplyShorts(short a, short b)
{
    short aHigh = (short)((a >> 8) & 0xFF);
    short aLow  = (short)(a & 0xFF);
    short bHigh = (short)((b >> 8) & 0xFF);
    short bLow  = (short)(b & 0xFF);
    short lowLow = (short)(aLow * bLow);
    short highLow = (short)(aHigh * bLow);
    short lowHigh = (short)(aLow * bHigh);
    short highHigh = (short)(aHigh * bHigh);
    short[] result = new short[2];
    result[1] = (short)(lowLow & 0xFF);
    short carry = (short)((lowLow >> 8) & 0xFF);
    short middle = (short)(highLow + lowHigh + carry);

    //We cheat here and just increase highLow with carry as we know
    //carry is at most 0xFE and highLow is at most 0xFE01 so adding
    //the carry to it can never overflow. If we didn't know this 
    //we'd need to adapt this to check overflow on summing 3 numbers
    highLow += carry;
    short middleCarry = (short) ((((highLow & lowHigh) | ((highLow | lowHigh) & ~middle)) >>> 7) & 0x100);

    //We bit shift by 7 here and mask on 0x100 to save us an operation as
    //the overflow always applies as a increment on highHigh above the area we 
    //increment with the middle.

    result[1] |= (short)((middle & 0xFF) << 8);
    result[0] = (short)((middle >> 8) & 0xFF);
    result[0] = (short)(result[0] + highHigh + middleCarry);
    return result;
}

This should then work on all possible values. As Maarten Bodewes also said, doing new short[2] like we do in the code is a big no-no in production, as you want to use an array to hold this that you know isn't gonna leak memory.
